# Using perf for application routine tracing

Tags: linux, debugging, arguments, perf

Is it possible to capture the arguments to userspace function in a precompiled binary with the linux perf tool ?  I couldn't figure this out via the documentation or google ?

If not any other suggestions ?
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it with perf but there other ways. If gdb is suitable then use it. If it is suitable for example because of performance problems then use SystemTap:

1) your precompiled binary has debug information and you can use gdb
   just attach to a running process, put breakpoint and possibly add command for it:
   break your_function
   command
   info args
   continue
   end

2) your precompiled binary does not have debug information and you can use gdb
   In this situation you need to know a calling convetion. For example for x64_86
   break your_function
   command
   info register rdi
   continue
   end

3) your precompiled binary has debug information, you cannot use gdb but can use SystemTap
   Then something like this:

```
sudo stap params.stp -x <PID>  'process("your-process-name").function("your_function")'

> cat params.stp

function trace(extra)
{
  printf("params:%s\n", extra)
}

probe $1.call { trace($$parms$$) }
```